# Broken pipe error when running Gradle test

Tags: java, unit-testing, gradle, testng

I've got a problem regarding running tests in gradle. I know that in other machines my gradle config works but in mine unfortunately not. We have got junit test and testNG and both of them, when try to execute, produces stacktrace like this:

```
Could not write standard input into: Gradle Worker 1.
java.io.IOException: The pipe is being closed
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:318)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.streams.ExecOutputHandleRunner.run(ExecOutputHandleRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:66)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Which continuously will produce this error with different number (Gradle Worker 2, Gradle Worker 3, etc). Has anybody ever faced similar problem?

I'm using gradle 1.6.

EDIT: I forgot to tell that I'm using gradle wrapper

EDIT: After changing to version 1.12 I'm receiving error:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.InvalidUserDataException: Could not create task '(custome taks name)': Unknown argument(s) in task definition: [mustRunAfter]
11:20:17.990 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.TaskFactory.validateArgs(TaskFactory.java:147)
11:20:17.991 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.TaskFactory.checkTaskArgsAndCreateDefaultValues(TaskFactory.java:134)
11:20:17.991 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.TaskFactory.createTask(TaskFactory.java:72)
```

EDIT: Ok I think I have found what cause this problem - ***it was Antivirus***. When I disable it script moves a little bit forward but ended with:

```
org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.ConnectException: Could not connect to server [e42b57ea-ced6-4bb6-9369-3186ab4983d6 port:63631, addresses:[/127.0.0.1, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]]. Tried addresses: [/127.0.0.1, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1].
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.TcpOutgoingConnector.connect(TcpOutgoingConnector.java:62)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedClient.getConnection(MessageHubBackedClient.java:35)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:54)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:35)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.child.ImplementationClassLoaderWorker.execute(ImplementationClassLoaderWorker.java:85)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.child.ImplementationClassLoaderWorker.execute(ImplementationClassLoaderWorker.java:41)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:43)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:32)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.launcher.BootstrapClassLoaderWorker.call(BootstrapClassLoaderWorker.java:46)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.launcher.BootstrapClassLoaderWorker.call(BootstrapClassLoaderWorker.java:32)
    at jarjar.org.gradle.process.internal.launcher.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:32)
    at jarjar.org.gradle.process.internal.launcher.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:37)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

Searching with google on this error gives me nothing (only some old gradle 1.1 errors info). Anybody faced this kind of problem?

Comment: I'd try with the latest Gradle version.

Comment: The 1.12 error could mean that there is a mistake in the build script that goes undetected in 1.6.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whew, after whole day struggling with gradle I think I've finally found what cause problems. Guilty of that was antivirus - COMODO. After uninstalling it and installing another one, everything started to working fine. So all Gradle Users - **please be careful with COMODO because even disabled, it could cause problems when using Gradle** . Be aware :)

Answer (score 6):

I faced the similar issue while running the test classes. I can able to build the project, but I couldn't able to run, so after some research I found one of the solution, which is to remove the some of the workerThread-jar from the .gradle/cache folder. I tried and it worked for me. You can use below commands to solve this.

1. In terminal I invoked `gradle test --info` command,

In response, I receive the logs, where I searched the for the

> Gradle worker Daemon

key, to fetch the location of my gradle-worker.jar. Typically in windows you can find this under the following location C:\Users\.gradle\caches\\workerMain\gradle-worker.jar.

To fix this, one approach is to remove the the workerMain folder itself, and run the test classes.

Answer (score 1):

You really don't need to disable or remove COMODO Antivirus. Just do the following steps:

1. Go to COMODO Client Panel
2. Open the Advanced Tasks option under the Task menu.
3. See all active tasks and select the Gradle process that is being blocked.
4. Right click on the task and 'Add to Trusted Files'

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error, except it said Gradle Worker 2. I restarted my command line (powershell) and then tried to build again with gradle and it worked.  I had changed my environment variables to point to the Java version the project was expecting and had not thought to restart- not sure if that had anything to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers here were helpful in my case.
What I had to do was disable the *coroutine agent*.

1. Open **Settings** (*File - Settings*)
2. Select **Kotlin** under *Build... - Debugger - Data Views*
3. **Check** the box "Disable coroutine agent"

[image]

Alternatively, go to your *build.gradle* file and upgrade the version used for the coroutines dependencies.