# Can't debugging JUnit + Roboloctric test in Android Studino with gradle

Tags: android, junit, gradle, robolectric

Yesterday it work fine!

But today i can't run with debug junit test. I don't understand what happens.
**Logcat:**

```
17:25:43.540 [ERROR] [system.err] ERROR: transport error 202: connect failed: Connection refused                                   
17:25:43.540 [QUIET] [system.out] FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
17:25:43.540 [ERROR] [system.err] ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)       
17:25:43.541 [ERROR] [system.err] JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [../../../src/share/back/debugInit.c:741]
17:25:43.927 [ERROR] [org.gradle.process.internal.streams.ExecOutputHandleRunner] Could not write standard input into: Gradle Test Executor 2.
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:318)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.streams.ExecOutputHandleRunner.run(ExecOutputHandleRunner.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

**UPD**
In this question "[Broken pipe error when running Gradle test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24548085/broken-pipe-error-when-running-gradle-test)" was a problem in antivirus. But I dont have it.

Comment: Broken pipe error? This is caused by writing to a connection when the other end has already closed it...

Comment: Or may be, you are sending something invalid to server..

Comment: @BharathMg >you are sending something invalid to server.. what do you mean?

Comment: Are you able to run and is it only debugging that doesn't work?

Comment: @AlexFlorescu Debugging mode does not work. If just run, it works well

Answer (score 1):

Did you have any connectivity issues?

> ERROR: transport error 202: connect failed: Connection refused

I had similar problem when executing my tests through proxy.

Comment: I dont have connectivity issues