# Problems with testing in project with gradle

Tags: java, gradle, javafx, junit

I want to use junt 4 for testing in my project, i added new class and one method to it for testing, when i try to tun it, i have this problem, how should i fix it.
When i try to run test i have a problem:

```
Could not write standard input to Gradle Test Executor 6.
java.io.IOException:
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:354)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:81)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:142)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.streams.ExecOutputHandleRunner.forwardContent(ExecOutputHandleRunner.java:67)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.streams.ExecOutputHandleRunner.run(ExecOutputHandleRunner.java:52)
    at 
...
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test'.
> No tests found for given includes: [SimpleTest.test](filter.includeTestsMatching)
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 0s
5 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 3 up-to-date
```

My build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
  id 'application'
  id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.8'
  id 'org.beryx.jlink' version '2.12.0'
}

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}


javafx {
    version = "14"
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml' ]
}

mainClassName = "$moduleName/org.openjfx.MainApp"

jlink {
    options = ['--strip-debug', '--compress', '2', '--no-header-files', '--no-man-pages'] ;
    launcher {
        name = 'hellofx'
    }
}
```

I don't now how to fix it, please help me!

Class with tests:

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class SimpleTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        Assert.assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

Also my projects [repository](https://github.com/Kirill-mol/APD-algorithm-visualization)

Comment: `Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output`. Have you tried this? 
Have you looked into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24548085/broken-pipe-error-when-running-gradle-test?

Comment: Please add you test class in the question

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your `build.gradle`. The problem is `Gradle` doesn't know how to find the tests as you haven't specified a test runner.

```
test {
   useJUnit()
}
```

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't help

Comment: i get the same errors, may be i should add anything to file module-info.java?

Comment: Oh, I just noticed. Is that a java module? I've not had any experience with those. Why opt for that in favour of gradle modules?

Comment: Because i want need to use it, because without it i can't use distribution in gradle without it and also i want to add fxml files.

Comment: Sorry, for junit 4 it seems it's `useJUnit()`. I've updated my comment above, checked out your  code, and it seems to be running fine. Can you please confirm?

Comment: But it doesn't help, i tried to use non-module structure, but without it i can't compile my project into distribution version using jlink, so may be you help me to solve this problem, because i need to run my project without idea, i tried many ways.

Comment: I'll have a play later on, I can't quite figure out why it wouldn't be working